# JSON compare element or existing of an element

Tags: php, json

How can I find and compare values in json?let say

```
{"data 1": {
    "product": "54",
    "info": {
        "browser": "Safari",
        "isp": "isp sample",
        "width": 500,
        "ip": 109.24.55.121,
        "uid": 124,
        "location": 10.23,123.90
    }
}
{"data 2": {
    "campaign": "2",
    "info": {
        "browser": "Mozilla",
        "isp": "isp sample",
        "width": 500,
        "ip": 109.24.55.121,
        "uid": 231,
        "location": 10.23,123.90
    }
}
{"data 3": {
    "campaign": "2",
    "info": {
        "browser": "Mozilla",
        "isp": "isp sample",
        "width": 500,
        "ip": 109.24.55.121,
        "uid": 227,
        "location": 10.23,123.90
    }
}
{"same data": {
    "campaign": "2",
    "info": {
        "browser": "Mozilla",
        "isp": "isp sample",
        "width": 500,
        "ip": 109.24.55.121,
        "uid": 227,
        "location": 10.23,123.90
    }
}
{"same data": {
    "campaign": "2",
    "info": {
        "browser": "Mozilla",
        "isp": "isp sample",
        "width": 500,
        "ip": 109.24.55.121,
        "uid": 227,
        "location": 10.23,123.90
    }
}
```

And I want to output the what are there similarities.on what string and what values.

Comment: do u want to remove duplicate value??

Comment: I want to compare on what string has a same values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = json_decode($your_json_data);

foreach($data as $datum) {
    .... do some processing ...
}
```

json_encode/json_decode will translate between native PHP arrays and native Javascript arrays/objects. You don't say which language you want to do the processing in, but since JSON *IS* javascript, there's no decoding to be done on the javascript side. just load up the data and go. On PHP, you'd want to decode it into a native PHP array first.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.I need to find the similarity on what (each)string has a same values with other strings in the objects.

Comment: @diecho: only if you want an actual array and not a stdClass object, which behaves mostly the same as an array anyways.

Comment: @mocca: well, that's up to you. I'm just explaining how you conver the JSON data into a PHP structure so you can analyse it in PHP. "similarities on string" means absolutely nothing to me. All strings are similar at certain levels "Oooh, they're all strings!"

Comment: @marc b you got a basic answer for this.I got a thousand strings that that has a same values on the other strings so it needs more logic to compare strings.thanks marc.

Comment: @marc b it is just a same concept on visualising facebook friends in a map or in a circle with lines who they share a common friends.